# How can I insert my json object into a Google chart line

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, charts, google-visualization

I have a google chart which currently has some hardcoded values that look like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Omzet', 'Omzet deze dag'],
    ['Ma',  1000],
    ['Di',  1170],
    ['Wo',  660],
    ['Do',  1030],
    ['Vr',  1030],
    ['Za',  1030],
    ['Zo',  1030]
]);
```

Now this is my json object that I want to use:

```
{"do":"11495","vr":"8985","za":0,"zo":"18990","ma":"27490","di":0,"wo":0}
```

How can I convert above object so that I can use it with google charts?

I tried following this tutorial [here](https://blog.programster.org/php-converting-data-for-google-charts). But my chart is empty when I use that code.

How can I use my json object for this chart?

Answer (score 0):

first, create the data table, for a line chart, the second column must be a number.

```
var jsonData = {"do":"11495","vr":"8985","za":0,"zo":"18990","ma":"27490","di":0,"wo":0};

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'x');
data.addColumn('number', 'y');
```

then loop on the keys of your json,
use the key as the x value,
and the valud of the key as y

since the value is stored as a string,
we will need to convert to a number,
using `parseFloat` or `parseInt`

```
for (var key in jsonData) {
  data.addRow([key, parseFloat(jsonData[key])]);
}
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {

  var jsonData = {"do":"11495","vr":"8985","za":0,"zo":"18990","ma":"27490","di":0,"wo":0};

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');

  for (var key in jsonData) {
    data.addRow([key, parseFloat(jsonData[key])]);
  }

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```